# System Status Off Custom Text

Tags: templating, status

I'd like a more personalized version of the offline page when the System Status is set to: Off. Is there a way to customize the page and/or change the text?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the System Status is set to "off", Craft will return a HTTP 503 response, which will then automatically trigger the "503.html" template in `craft/app/templates` to load, which is what you're seeing by default.

But if you put your own "503.html" in your `craft/templates` folder, Craft will load that one instead.  Same goes for the other HTTP status codes (400, 403, 404, 500, etc.).